# redirect to different pages on selected radio button using button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

The following image is a pop up that details risk warnings and then asks users to choose one of the two radio buttons. When 'I agree'(Submit) button is clicked, it should redirect to different pages based on which radio button is selected. The submit button has a jquery class.Can someone help me with a jquery code to check which radio button is selected and redirect to different pages?
[image: IMG]

The html is below,

```
    <div id="mask">
    </div>
    <!-- create white empty box -->
    <div id="boxes" class="bodytext">
        <!-- things that go in the box -->
        <div id="dialog" class="window">
           <strong>Disclaimer and Risk Warnings</strong>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="bodytext" style="overflow: auto; height: 160px; width: 500px;      border: activeborder 1px solid;">                   
            </div>
            <br/>
            <strong> Please select the user type that applies to you</strong>
            <br/>               
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>Private Clients</asp:ListItem>  
            <asp:ListItem>Professional Intermediaries</asp:ListItem>  
            </asp:RadioButtonList>             

            <p>
                <input id="AcceptButton" type="button" value="I Agree" class="close"  style="margin-left: 215px" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The jquery class is below

```
              $('.window .close').click(function (e) {

                $.cookie("CamSession1", "CAM");                   
                if ($('#Private Clients').is(':checked')) {
                    window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
                }
                else if ($('#Professional Intermediaries').is(':checked')) {
                    window.location.replace("http://exchange.com");
                }
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#mask').hide();
                $('.window').hide();
            });
```

Comment: post rendered html of RadioButtonList

Comment: why are you using runat server radio button?

Comment: No particular reason, thought I'll do the redirect on the code behind.  But it already has a jquery class to hide the mask it creates before popping up, so I was thinking of adding the redirects in the jquery class itself. Should I use input type radio instead ?

Comment: yes, you should. because you don't need runat server control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Html

```
<div id="mask">
    </div>
    <!-- create white empty box -->
    <div id="boxes" class="bodytext">
        <!-- things that go in the box -->
        <div id="dialog" class="window">
           <strong>Disclaimer and Risk Warnings</strong>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="bodytext" style="overflow: auto; height: 160px; width: 500px;      border: activeborder 1px solid;">                   
            </div>
            <br/>
            <strong> Please select the user type that applies to you</strong>
            <br/>               
            <input type="radio" name="rdotnc" id="rdo1" />Private Clients
            <input type="radio" name="rdotnc" id="rdo2"/>Professional Intermediaries
            </asp:RadioButtonList>             

            <p>
                <input id="AcceptButton" type="button" value="I Agree" class="close"  style="margin-left: 215px" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
$('.window .close').click(function (e) {
                //$.cookie("CamSession1", "CAM");  
                if ($('#rdo1').is(':checked')) {
                    window.location.replace("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
                }
                else if ($('#rdo2').is(':checked')) {
                    window.location.replace("http://www.exchange.com");
                }
                $('#mask').hide();
                $('.window').hide();
            });
```

Check fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u8jD9/)